# Jackson Deserialization Error using a JSON ArrayList

Tags: java, json, jackson

I have the following JSON string I'm deserializing (using Jackson version 2.4.8) to an object of type Test using inheritence which works fine:

```
{
  "TEST": {
    "CONDITIONS": [
      {
        "KEY": "KEYA",
        "VALUES": [
          "VALUEA"
        ],
        "OPERATOR": ""
      }
    ],
    "CONSEQUENCE": {
      "ACTIONTYPE": "TEST",
      "ACTION": [
        {
          "CONDITIONS": [
            {
              "KEY": "KEYB",
              "VALUES": [
                "VALUEB"
              ],
              "OPERATOR": ""
            }
          ],
          "CONSEQUENCE": {
            "ACTIONTYPE": "CONCATENATE",
            "ACTION": [
              "VALUEA",
              "VALUEB"
            ]
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

My configuration looks like this:

```
ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
mapper.enable(SerializationFeature.WRAP_ROOT_VALUE).enable(DeserializationFeature.UNWRAP_ROOT_VALUE);           
Test test = mapper.readValue(json, Test.class);
```

And the Test object looks like this:

```
@JsonRootName("TEST")
@NoArgsConstructor
public class Test {

    public Test(List<Condition> conditions, BaseConsequence<?> baseConsequence){
        this.conditions = conditions;
        this.baseConsequence = baseConsequence;     
    }

    @JsonProperty("CONDITIONS")
    private List<Condition> conditions;

    @JsonProperty("CONSEQUENCE")
    private BaseConsequence<?> baseConsequence;

}
```

When I change the above JSON to an ArrayList of `[{"TEST": {...}},{"TEST": {...}}]` and try deserializing the list into a wrapper class using the `@JsonProperty("TEST")`:

```
@Data
@NoArgsConstructor
public class TestCase {

    public TestCase(List<Test> tests){
        this.tests = tests;
    }

    @JsonProperty("TEST")   
    private List<Test> tests;   
}
```

the deserialisation fails and i get the following error:

```
com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonMappingException: Unexpected token (START_ARRAY), expected START_OBJECT: Current token not START_OBJECT (needed to unwrap root name 'TestCase'), but START_ARRAY
 at [Source: [{"TEST":{"CONDITIONS":[{"KEY":"KEYA","VALUES":["VALUEA"],"OPERATOR":""}],"CONSEQUENCE":{"ACTIONTYPE":"TEST","ACTION":[{"CONDITIONS":[{"KEY":"KEYB","VALUES":["VALUEB"],"OPERATOR":""}],"CONSEQUENCE":{"ACTIONTYPE":"CONCATENATE","ACTION":["VALUEA","VALUEB"]}}]}}},{"TEST":{"CONDITIONS":[{"KEY":"KEYA","VALUES":["VALUEA"],"OPERATOR":""}],"CONSEQUENCE":{"ACTIONTYPE":"TEST","ACTION":[{"CONDITIONS":[{"KEY":"KEYB","VALUES":["VALUEB"],"OPERATOR":""}],"CONSEQUENCE":{"ACTIONTYPE":"CONCATENATE","ACTION":["VALUEA","VALUEB"]}}]}}}]; line: 1, column: 1]
```

If it works fine for a single JSON, why does it fail with an ArrayList of Test?

Comment: I guess you're calling `mapper.readValue(json, TestCase.class);`, right? If so the problem is your JSON: it represents a list of `Test` instances and not an object. Try to use a `TypeReference`: `mapper.readValue( json, new TypeReference<List<Test>>() { } );`.

Comment: @Thomas, yes that's correct, i was using `TestCase test = mapper.readValue(json, TestCase.class);`, i'll try your suggestion now.

Comment: One additional thing (I'm not sure here though): when deserializing a JSON list there is no real root so your JSON should probably look like `[{"CONDITIONS":...},{"CONDITIONS":...}, ...]`, i.e. without the surrounding object that contains the `"TEST"` field. Alternatively use your `TestCase` but name the list `TESTS`: `{"TESTS":[{"CONDITIONS":...},{"CONDITIONS":...}, ...]}`.

Comment: I tried your suggestion Thomas but getting the following error now: `com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonMappingException: Unexpected token (START_ARRAY), expected START_OBJECT: Current token not START_OBJECT (needed to unwrap root name 'List'), but START_ARRAY
 at [Source: [{"TEST"....`

Comment: If you read the message carefully you'll see that in order to unwrap the root name (which you specified) the JSON must be an object, not a list/array (see my other comment as well).

Comment: @Thomas, sorry i don't get it. If i want to use the class TestCase and change the JSON name from `"TEST":{` to `"TESTS":{` it still fails?  Can you expand on your second point above please. If i change the JSON as you describe  do i need to change the TestCase classaswell?

Comment: No, `TestCase` would be the root element that is being unwrapped. Since it contains a _list_ of tests you need to change your JSON to represent this: `{"TESTS":[ ... ]}` where `...` are the individual tests. Since those aren't root elements anymore you should use the value of `"TEST"` instead of the object that contains that field, hence the final JSON would look like `{"TESTS":[{"CONDITIONS":...},{"CONDITIONS":...}, ...]}` (each `{"CONDITIONS":...}` represents _one_ instance of `Test`)

Comment: Thomas, i changed the JSON to match `{"TESTS":[{"CONDITIONS":...},{"CONDITIONS":...}, ...]}` and used `TestCase testCase = mapper.readValue(json, TestCase.class);` but still getting an error: `com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonMappingException: Root name 'TESTS' does not match expected ('TestCase') for type [simple type, class mypackage.TestCase]
 at [Source: {"TESTS":[{"CONDITIONS":[{"KEY":"KEYA","VALUES":["VALUEA"],"OPERATOR":""}],"CONSEQUENCE":{"ACTIONTYPE":"TEST","ACTION":[{"TEST":{"CONDITIONS":[{"KEY":"KEYB","VALUES":["VALUEB"],"OPERATOR":""}],"CONSEQUENCE":{"ACTION...`

Comment: Did you define the root name that should be unwrapped? If that doesn't work as well, try without `TestCase` and root unwrapping (and ofc just `[{"CONDITIONS":...},{"CONDITIONS":...}, ...]`, i.e. not wrapped at all).

Comment: No, it was defined in TEST.java using @JsonRootName("TEST")

Comment: Use the same principle annotation on TestCase class as TESTS

Comment: I tried annotating my TestCase with @JsonRootName("TESTS") but thats giving me the following error: `com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonMappingException: Can not deserialize instance of mypackage.TestCase out of START_ARRAY token
 at [Source: {"TESTS":[{"CONDITIONS":[{"KEY":"KEYA","VALUES":["VALUEA"],"OPERATOR":""}],"CONSEQUENCE":{"ACTIONTYPE":"TEST","ACTION":[{"TEST":{"CONDITIONS":[{"KEY":"KEYB","VALUES":["VALUEB"],"OPERATOR":""}],"CONSEQUENCE":{"ACTIONTYPE":"CONCATENATE"...`

Comment: Thanks Thomas, i removed the root unwrapping: `mapper.enable(SerializationFeature.WRAP_ROOT_VALUE).enable(DeserializationFeature.UNWRAP_ROOT_VALUE);` and the `@JsonRootName("TEST")` from my Test class, added `List<Test> tests = mapper.readValue(json, new TypeReference<List<Test>>(){});` and reformatted my JSON to  `[{"CONDITIONS":...},{"CONDITIONS":...}, ...]` and this worked!!